# ssh-keygen won't print '=' symbol in sha256 of pubkey, but python will

Tags: hash, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, sha

When I run

```
ssh-keygen -lf my_key.pub
```

I get a fingerprint of the type:

```
something
```

When I do it to the same base64 encoded public key, but in python, with the code

```
    def to_sha_256(b64pubkey):
        sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
        sha256.update(base64.b64decode(b64pubkey))
        hash_sha256 = sha256.digest()
        return hash_sha256
    def to_base_64(plaintext):
        return str(base64.b64encode(plaintext), 'utf-8')

    fingerprint = to_base_64(to_sha_256(b64pubkey))
```

I get

```
something=
```

What is that `=` in the end and which one is correct?

Answer (score 5):

`base64` uses equal signs for padding if the number of encoded bytes is not a multiple of 3.
However, the padding is not always  mandatory and its use varies between implementations:

> In theory, the padding character is not needed for decoding, since the number of missing bytes can be calculated from the number of Base64 digits. In some implementations, the padding character is mandatory, while for others it is not used.

[(Source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

For example, since this string has only 7 bytes, `==` is appended to pad the value to a multiple of 3:

```
$ echo -n "1234567" | base64
MTIzNDU2Nw==
```

So both variants are correct. If in doubt, use the padded one.

Comment: Readers of this answer may find the configuration method [`withoutPadding`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#withoutPadding--) in Java interesting. There is also an RFC for base 64, which as [this section in it about padding](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-3.2). Of course the RFC may not be used at all, base 64 existed before the RFC.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: there is not only one but several RFC which attempt to describe Base64. See also https://xkcd.com/927/